# Google sheets - Query - Select where it contains more than one result

Tags: sql, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, matching

I have a spreadsheet with several names of drugs, such as "amoxicillin". And, on the other tab are the drugs, only with their association "amoxicillin + potassium clavulanate".

I need the spreadsheet to return all fields where the drug is "mentioned" in tab 2. Something like: "Return everything that has the word "amoxicillin", similar to searching with Ctrl + F.

However, I would like the results to be in the same column. And I did it by query: ​

`=IF(A:A<>"";query('Page2'!A:A;"Select * WHERE A CONTAINS '"&A2&"' ");"Not found") ​`

The problem is that the CONTAINS '"&A2&"'​ ​only returns the data referring to this line, but I needed it to be repeated in the A3 and A4 lines without me having to change the query. Making all the results structured in the same column.

If possible to do this by query, it would be even better if you could group it this way:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Amoxicillin | Amoxicillin Esomeprazole + Clarithromycin |
| Amoxicillin | Amoxicillin + Potassium Clavulanate |
| Azithromycin | Azithromycin |

Comment: It's not very clear what would be your input and output. Those two times "Amoxicilin" are written by you??, or you expect to write Amoxicilin in A1 and Azythromycin in A2, and then in other two columns return the "query" with the name of the drug in one and how it's mentioned in the other?

Comment: I have a list of unique drug names, such as amoxicillin and azithromycin. I need a formula that refers to all drugs where amoxicillin is mentioned, such as: 
Amoxicillin + Potassium Clavulanate
Amoxicillin Esomeprazole + Clarithromycin

Comment: Are you able to share a sample spreadsheet that shows your inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: @MiguelRiveraRios Sure! https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18m6Al_qFo2ibBemdMuc_JqCXJKOKKWWIWPsCICSYG_Y/edit?usp=sharing

I would like something like Pag3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=reduce({'Pag1'!A1\'Pag2'!A1};tocol('Pag1'!A2:A;1);lambda(a;c;vstack(a;
       let(Σ;filter('Pag2'!A:A;search(c;'Pag2'!A:A));hstack(wrapcols(c;counta(Σ);c);Σ)))))
```

[image]